# Crash my app when synchronise my core data server to app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When i synchronise my core data so most of the time my app crash. so what can i do for resolve this crash point.This APP_DELEGATE.managedObjectContext most of the time crash.

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![APP_DELEGATE.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR while saving UserList - %@", error);
    }
```

> ERROR while saving UserList - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "(null)" UserInfo={NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=(" (entity: QuizOption; id: 0x7fbe5dca67a0  ; data: {\n    optionText = Inferior;\n    questionId = 3;\n    socialIdOption = 12;\n})"), NSUnderlyingException=Cannot update object that was never inserted.}

```
2016-03-11 11:29:37.323 CuztomisePharma[1045:43638] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x7fbe5dd43cf0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a826e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109e4bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a8267c4 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 132
    3   CoreData                            0x0000000108ccba24 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 2932
    4   CuztomisePharma                     0x00000001089c5cea -[LoginManager getUserByUserId:] + 698
    5   CuztomisePharma                     0x00000001088746a1 -[SyncManager firstTimeSync] + 801
    6   CuztomisePharma                     0x00000001087e1399 -[LoginViewController loginServerCall] + 1273
    7   Foundation                          0x0000000109ad5dfb __NSThread__start__ + 1198
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d0f605a _pthread_body + 131
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d0f5fd7 _pthread_body + 0
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d0f33ed thread_start + 13
)
```

Comment: Show the complete crash log.

Comment: ERROR while saving UserList - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "(null)" UserInfo={NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=(
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x7fbe5dca7ce0> (entity: QuizOption; id: 0x7fbe5dca67a0 <x-coredata:///QuizOption/tE1879FF0-93F8-4936-9847-E68315271B3031> ; data: {\n    optionText = Inferior;\n    questionId = 3;\n    socialIdOption = 12;\n})"
), NSUnderlyingException=Cannot update object that was never inserted.}

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Well I'd start with the error text "Cannot update object that was never inserted".

Comment: That's the error message.  It makes sense to me.

Comment: Please explain in brief i am not getting your point #trojanfoe

Comment: It's not my "point" you don't get, it's the error message.  You are attempting to update a row that doesn't exist.